# Azure Functions Open Converter

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to add a middleware/formatter to an Azure Function. Basically I want to achieve the same thing like `InputFormatters` in ASP.NET MVC or in other words "hijack the input formatting from any source(ServiceBus, Http, ...etc)".

I tried to add an open converter from `Message` => `OpenType`, `String` => `OpenType`, `OpenType` => `OpenType` but nothing worked.

[image: Converter registration]

I followed this [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings) but it seems to be out of date.

Comment: MVC is specific to HTTP, but Azure Functions has a variety of possible triggers (http, queues, blobs, etc). Azue Functions won't let you hijack "from any source", you have to pick a specific source (attribute).  For example, you could specify a binding from CloudQueueMessage to OpenType, and then invoke your custom converter.

Comment: Also, you can't do an OpenType-->OpenType. That's too generic and the binding engine wouldn't know when to apply it.

Comment: @MikeS I did try to apply the conversion on the ServiceBus Message but it didn’t work, hence my question. I just need a proper working example for either the http or the service bus triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to do is to modify the behaviour of the pre-built bindings?! If so, take a look at their source code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/tree/dev/src

You can easily clone that, make you changes and use that like a custom binding. However, I'm not sure if things like scaling logic will still work then, even if you derive from the official bindings.

Comment: thanks for the heads up but I don't want to copy the whole trigger just to transform the payload, feels that this functionality is not well implemented/used in Azure Functions yet.